# client.commands.has() not working with normal input

Tags: discord.js

To get the files with commands (such as ping.js)

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Play some ping pong.',
    execute(message, args) {
        const bot = require('../bot.js');

        message.channel.send('pong!');
        bot.log(message, '$ping', message.guild.name);
    },
};
```

I use this in bot.js

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command_file = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command_file.name, command_file);
}
```

I'm trying to set the variable for the command with this:

```
let command = '';

if(message.content.includes(' ')){
        command = message.content.substr(1, message.content.indexOf(' ')).toLowerCase();
    } else {
        command = message.content.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    }
```

which returns the name of the command as a string, like 'info' or 'ping'.

But, when I put that variable into `client.commands.has()` it doesnt find the command and returns back with this:

```
if(!client.commands.has(command)) return;
```

I cant find any answers to this online so I figured I'd ask, sorry if this doesnt fit

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```js
const cmd =
  message.client.commands.get(command) ||
  message.client.commands.find(
    (cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(command) // if you're also using aliases
  );

if (!command) return;
```